# How to generate random numbers 0 to 26 using crypto.generateValues()

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to generate random numbers 0 to 26 using crypto.getRandomValues().
help

```
var array = new Uint32Array(1);
window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);

console.log(Math.floor(array[0] * 5));
```

Comment: if you want a number between 0 and 26 you probably want to use `Math.random()`...

Comment: the thing is using crypto.getRandomValues()

Comment: "the thing" is what?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, personally you can use `Math.random()` which is made for those things:

```
let number = Math.random() * 26
```

But math-wise, you can just get a number between 0 and N using the module class N+1, so like:

```
let number = yourFunctionThatUsesCrypto() % 27 // [0,26]
let number = yourFunctionThatUsesCrypto() % 26 // [0,26)
```

Otherwise, as suggested from *@Mr. Polywhirl* you can [scale the number between 0,1 (normalize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694626/generating-random-numbers-0-to-1-with-crypto-generatevalues) and then multiply it by the limit you want (in this case, 26)